# php header function not working due to .htaccess rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Following are the contents from my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond $1 !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|mp3|wav|txt)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

I have following php code inside the index.php which checks page (i.e. `myproject`) and redirect requests:

```
header('Location:http://mynewsite.com/myproject/') ;
exit;
```

When i use `www.example.com/myproject` it should be redirected to `mynewsite/myproject` instead it is getting redirected to `www.example.com/mynewsite.com/myproject`

Any idea what am i missing here ?

Comment: You're missing the fact that `mod_rewrite` doesn't affect php's `header` function behaviour. So check your headers and find a real issue.

Comment: Does `mynewsite` have an domain tld extension at the end in real code?

Comment: yes. I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you rewrite your header function as:

```
header('Location: http://mynewsite.com/myproject/');
exit;
```